# Simple web GUI to capture user data

Tags: javascript, web

I need to develop a simple web page that accepts user information( name, age, birthdate, etc) and saves the data to a CSV or a text file to the server. I currently use Google sheets, but I need something that's more customizable and something that does some simple error checking. Are there any open source frameworks out there that I can use to put something together in a couple hours? I have a mechanical engineering background, and I'm not too familiar with web technologies. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quick question, when you say "[saves] CSV or text file," do you need the files to be server-side only, or stored (saved) to the user's machine?

Comment: These files will be saved on the server side.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried since it seems like a lot of work. Also you have not mention what server language you want to work with i.e; php There are 2 parts an HTML form and the actual server code to save the data into a .csv file.

Comment: Let me give you a quick backstory on this project. I have been using Google forms for a while now to accomplish this task. But I've run into some issues now, and want to develop a customized solution. I cannot afford spend a lot of time on this, unless I can  justify the effort. I was under the impression that this would be a quick project. Ideally, I was hoping that there would be an opensource solution that I can easily customize and reuse for this project. A friend told me that JavaScript wouldn't have a steep learning curve and I should be able to put something together real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

JavaScript:

```
function saveUserData(url, data) {
  var csv = [],  // the array of values
      del = "="; // the "delimiter" or "separator"

  function handle(string) {
    return encodeURI(string)
      .replace(/,/g, "%2c");
  }

  for(var property in data)
    csv.push(property + del + handle(data[property]));
    // "name=John Doe,dob=Jan 1%2c 2000"

  $.post(url, {data: csv.toString()})
  .done(function(returned_data) {
    // if you need this later
  }, "json");

  // "url" the the url to send the data to
  // "data:" will likely be determined by the server you're using
  // "json" will make "returned_data" a JSON object (if the server supports it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tesla88,

In your case, you need to write a server-side script. Below are 3 links that will show you how to 
[open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [write](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), and [close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) a file.

That's how far as I would elaborate on my answer, you need to show us that you actually did the work, and if you ran into issues, you can ask here again.

I hope the above helps. 
-Anthony